# separate numeric input android

Tags: android

I need to separate the input of an Edit Text on android, the input is in this format 4589, so I want to send the 45 to a list view, and the 89 to a Edit Text, somebody can help me I will appreciate it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not clear. But you can try something like this

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
String input = et.getText().toString();

String toEditText = input.substring(0,2); //45
String toListView = input.substring(2); //89
```

now you have the strings, use `setText()` to print

Answer (score 0):

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(editText.getText());
int listNum = a / 100; //45
int editNum = a - listNum*100; //89
```

Here is a solution using integer division.